# Get the center point between many GameObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a game in which you can control X characters at the same time in the same form and they can die at any time. My problem is when I want the game camera to include all these gameobjects.

**I thought that a good option is to calculate the central point between the gameobjects in the scene and make the camera follow that point at a certain distance.**

I already have the camera code, but I still need to know how to get that central point or another way of doing it. In addition, the camera does not follow any of the axes (X, Y, Z) linearly, since it is placed in such a way that is the view is isometric (the game is in 3D).

As a last important fact, it is that all gameobjects that are running in the game (that are alive), are stored in a `public static List <GameObject>` to be able to access the components of these gameobjects at any time. Also, if a character (gameobject) dies or is born, the list is updated without problems.

I leave you a graphic example with three different cases, being the black points, the characters that are in the scene (gameobjects) and the red points, the central point (vector) that I would like to find.

[image]

Also, I leave the camera code so you can test if you have any solution:

```
public class Camera_Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 newPos;
    public static List<GameObject> playersInGame = new List<GameObject>();

    void Update() {

        // Get Central Vector

        // Replace playersInGame[0].transform.position with central vector
        //newPos = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, "central vector", Time.deltaTime);

        newPos = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, playersInGame[0].transform.position, Time.deltaTime);
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);

    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to take the average x and and average y.

That would look like the following:

```
var totalX = 0f;
var totalY = 0f;
foreach(var player in playersInGame)
{
     totalX += player.transform.position.x;
     totalY += player.transform.position.y;
}
var centerX = totalX / playersInGame.Count;
var centerY = totalY / playersInGame.Count;
```

Let me know if this works for you (don't have access to Unity at the moment), but I put together an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGd99I

Comment: It works perfect (adding modifications to adapt it to my code). It's so simple that I have embarrassed to have asked. Thank you very much for opening my eyes!

Comment: @VickyVicent Good solution which works with a small number of objects, but if there's a larger collection you can end up with an odd central point depending on the distribution of the objects. For example, if you had 20 objects clustered in one area, then another object a ways off, the central point calculated here would be really quite far from the outlier object. Just something to keep in mind!

Comment: @Serlite You're right. I tried it with many and with one away from the rest and something weird came out (although the center is still correct), but as I have controlled when each new gameobject will come out, it is not a problem. Something interesting that can be included in the code is the option that the camera zoom-in/zoom-out if the object is out of view of the camera, but you have to control the gameobjects equally. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: By getting the average you don't find the center point. The best way is to find the max x, max y, min x and min y then you get your self the corners of a rectangle so you could calculate the center point.

Answer (score 7):

To have a solution that your camera can be best positioned to see all of your objects, then try this:

```
public Vector3 FindCenterOfTransforms(List<Transform> transforms)
{
    var bound = new Bounds(transforms[0].position, Vector3.zero);
    for(int i = 1; i < transforms.Count; i++)
    {
        bound.Encapsulate(transforms[i].position);
    }
    return bound.center;
}
```